# How to determine stream end in a asynchronous socket server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, stream

I’m trying to write a asynchronous socket in c#. I read a lot of msdn articles and found those two examples: [server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I understood the sample code an use this to implement my own async socket. In the example the server checks for `<EOF>` to determine the end of the stream and send a response. I would like to know without checking for a special literal when the stream ends. My idea was to check `(bytesRead > 0)` and call `handler.BeginReceive()` recursively.
See following:

> Original

```
if (bytesRead > 0) {
    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
        state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
    // more data.
    content = state.sb.ToString();
    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
        // All the data has been read from the 
        // client. Display it on the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
            content.Length, content );
        // Echo the data back to the client.
        Send(handler, content);
    } else {
        // Not all data received. Get more.
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
}
```

> My idea

```
if (received > 0)
{
    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}
else
    Send(handler, state.sb.ToString());
```

If I replace the original part with my part the program stops running.
I guess the client execute `EndSend()` in `SendCallback()` and block the Thread after `receiveDone.WaitOne()` in `StartClient()`. How could I pass this? Is it necessary to use a token which determine the end of the stream?

Are there any other good example codes? I just found those two.

(Evidence. The server should receive online clients and put them into a circulate buffer from this buffer he should read and process the records with multithreads. )

**Edit**

If I use folling:

```
if (receive > 0)
    state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, receive));
if (receive == StateObject.BufferSize)
    state.listener.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
else
    Send(state.listener, state.sb.ToString());
```

Everyting works fine, I guess. Is it ok? Or miss I something?

If I combine the two ifs, it doesn’t work again. Why?

`if(receive > 0 || receive == StateObject.BufferSize)` -> `if(receive > 0) // Not working.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your version of code is that you initiate `BeginReceive` always but in one situation i.e. when there are `0` bytes received. In fact the end of transmission will occur most of the time when you receive an amount of data that is non-zero and less than your buffer size (and sometimes when it is exactly the size of the buffer). Receiving `0` bytes will never happen because that means *no transmission* rathen than *end of transmission*. That is assuming that sender ends transmission by closing connection.

There is number of ways to indicate end of transmission:

- sender closes connection
- special sequance is sent (like EOF)
- receiver got what he expected (because it got header first)

Problem with first approach is that closing (and reopening) connection is usually expensive.
Problem with header is that if you miss a header (because of some network problem) you are lost - you do not know when the next header will come because you do not know when the current data packet will end (lost header). Easiest recovery in case of problems provides EOF in some form. It does not have to literally be `<EOF>` string, it can be anything that would (most probably) never occur in your normal data stream.

Having said that, there is nothing stopping you from using combination of header with `EOF` or a header which would contain a special sequence marking beginning of a record.

Answer (score 0):

The situation when you can determine that the network stream has ended is when the remote end does a graceful shutdown of the connection. This will make `EndRead` return zero. This is of course not an optimal approach if you want to send data back to the remote end. You would essentially have to create a new connection back to the client instead of reusing the initial connection. This is certainly something that you can do, but it usually won't work well for example if the client is behind a NAT router.

What the sample code does when it checks for `EOF` is enforcing an application level protocol. The underlying network stack has no understanding of the payload that it delivers to your application, and thus cannot determine that the conceptual stream has ended. This is something where your application has the responsibility. Checking for a tag or token is a very simple way to do that.

Comment: Using a token is a common way? I would like to send the length of the content first, is that possible? If received is equalt to the buffer size I could assume that there is more data?

Comment: It is common to use some kind of delimiter, but sending the length (or more often the number of octets) before sending the data also occurs frequently. As long as you have a protocol that both endpoints can agree on you're good to go.